# Problems with Cocotron

Tags: objective-c, cocotron

I've been trying to use Cocotron and installed it with the Instructions on their site, but when i try to build their example app with Cocotron it doesn't work and I get a load of errors about things being undeclared like `NSString` and `YES`. It seems Cocotron isn't doing its part.

What has gone wrong?

Here are some Pics of the errors:

[alt text http://snapplr.com/snap/xagj](http://snapplr.com/snap/xagj)
[alt text http://snapplr.com/snap/2qcy](http://snapplr.com/snap/2qcy)

Comment: Hi Joshua, can you please enlighten us by telling us how you fixed the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa.h (the main header file of the Cocoa framework) is not found by your IDE.
Your include path seems to be incorrect.

Otherwise, if you're developing for iPhone OS, there's just no Cocoa.h file...

Comment: It's for Mac/Win. What do you mean include path?

Comment: For Mac/Win? You are trying to use the Cocoa framework on Windows?!? O_o

Please add some more details if you want a correct answer...

Comment: Hellloooo! Thats what Cocotron does!

Comment: Anyway I have fixed the problem!